# Want to produce a key press when clicking a button

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a persistent floating toolbar to assist me in doing common tasks on my windows tablet (no keyboard) such as 'undo', 'copy' and 'delete'.
Right now I have this:

```
Gui, Destroy
Gui,+AlwaysOnTop
Gui,+ToolWindow
Gui,+Border
Gui, Add, Button, y5 w60, &Undo
Gui, Add, Button, y5 w60, &Delete
Gui, Add, Button, y8 h18, X
Gui, Show, y0
Return

ButtonUndo:
ControlSend,, ^z
Return

ButtonDelete:
ControlSend,, {Backspace}
Return

ButtonX:
ButtonCancel:
Gui, Destroy
ExitApp

End:
Reload
Return
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing anything other than making an error sound when I click the buttons. Do I need to tell it to focus on a different window somehow first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like the idea! The problem is that as soon as you click one of the buttons, the focus is taken away from the application that you want to control...
So you send the commands to your own AutoHotKey application...

A simple way to resolve this is to first send an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and then after e.g. a 20 ms sleep, send your commands.

```
ButtonUndo:
    Send, !{Esc} ; Changed from Alt+Tab
    Sleep, 20
    Send, ^z
Return
```

Comment: This ended up working with Send,, in place of ControlSend,,
the only problem is I can only have one window open at a time for it to be useful. I'm going to see if I cant use the WinExist function in some way to ignore the window containing the buttons

Comment: Why is it that you can only have one window open? Alt+Tab (set at good old XP-Style inside Windows 7) switches you back to te previous active application. I tested this with about 10 windows open.

Comment: The problem with winactivate is that you need to know the ID of the previous window, which you can't get at the moment you pressed a button. You could use a settimer loop...

Comment: With regard to Send v.s. ControlSend, I have to admit that I did not even look at that. I just looked at the reason why it did not send the data to the right window.

Comment: I think it's something to do with being windows 8. the metro app environment seems to be throwing the alt tab functionality a curve ball. will try alt+esc and the check window method though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for switching with Settimer

```
SetTimer, CheckWin, 100; Put at the beginning of your script   

CheckWin:
WinGetTitle, CurrName, A
if (CurrName = PrevName) ; check if window has been changed
    Return ; Only continue if an other application was activated
LastName = %PrevName% ; Use %LastName% in winactivate
PrevName = %CurrName% ; When new app, then sync AppName and PrevName
Return
```

Comment: Check my suggestion to use Alt+Esc first, that works on my machine as well and might work better and faster than having the script constantly monitor windows changes.